# Multiple tag search returns fewer results than single tag search

Tags: bug, tags, search

If I do a [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kdb) for the [kdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kdb) tag using `[kdb]` I see 935 results:

[image: Screenshot of number of results for [kdb] search]

But if I modify [the search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kdb+or+k) to `[kdb] or [k]` I see fewer results returned:

[image: Screenshot of number of results for [kdb] or [k] search]

What could be causing this issue? I'd be expecting to see 935 or more results using *or* in the search.

Comment: Err, maybe the `or` means *exclusive or* (aka `XOR` or `^`).

Comment: There are only 28 results for the k tag and on [page 46](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kdb+or+k?page=46&sort=newest&pagesize=15) of the search there are questions using both.

Comment: searching for questions only: [`[kdb] is:q`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkdb%5D+is%3Aq) gives 680 results

Comment: Looks like the combined result makes sense. I guess the question now is what is the extra stuff being returned with just the [tag:kdb] tag?

Comment: Interestingly, with the first search, if you ask it to show you 50 per page, it won't actually show you that many.

Comment: I think that the bug is caused by synonyms. I think the tag counter thingy counts some questions twice. Once for kbd and once for qlang. Then it removes duplicate results from the search. The first search doesn't actually return 935 results.

Comment: If you take the number of search results containing the tag [qlang] on a page and add it with the number of results on the page, you get the number of results you asked for per page.

Comment: The synonymization was pretty recent. Probably [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com).

Comment: I'm seeing similar behavior with the search term: `[msword] or [word-vba] or [vsto] or [office-js] or [openxml-sdk] or [openxml]` Mostly, I notice entries in the first tag are left out. For example, this one doesn't appear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777946/ms-word-continuos-highlighting-issue

Comment: @jakekimdsΨ Pagination is hard.